# Dial a phone number or allow someone to dial into a scheduled Google Hangout?

Tags: google-hangouts

I scheduled a Google Hangout from Google Calendar (under my personal Gmail account). I'd like to have a way for participants to join it by phone only - either them dialing in or me dialing out to them.

How can I do this? I tried installing the UberConference Google Hangouts app, but when I open it, I just see a panel saying that it is loading (have not been able to get it to load).

[image: hangouts screenshot]

I saw [this support article](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3187125?visit_id=1-636640693912467121-2583574309&rd=1), but I do not see a "call tab" as described.

Mac OS 10.12.6 , Chrome Version 67.0.3396.79 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: What about if you click "add Person"? (The left-most icon to the right of Google.) Does that give you an option for a phone number?

Comment: You _might_ need to have a Google Voice number (or Google Fi) in order to dial out to people.

Comment: @ale yes, clicking the "add person" icon was the way to do it! I added screenshots in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ale suggested, clicking the "add person" icon brings up this dialog

[image: add person dialog]

and from there, clicking the phone keypad icon (to the right of the "add names or email addresses" field) brings up another dialog from which you can dial a phone number.

[image: call phone dialog]